# Using matplotlib to make 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

Just trying to make a 3D plot of a constant (0). So I have

```
width = 1
dx = 0.1
X = np.arange(-width, width, dx)
Y = np.arange(-width, width, dx)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    Z.append(np.zeros(len(X[i])))
```

But when I try to run `Axes3D.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)` I get `plot_wireframe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Z'`. I need help understanding why this is, because `Z` is a 2D array like it should be, and I can't find many helpful examples with 3D plotting with matplotlib.

Answer (score 2):

The main point is that you cannot run `Axes3D.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)` by itself. Instead you need to create an instance of Axes3D and call its method [*]. Just like in the 2D case where you wouldn't call `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot(x,y)` but `ax.plot(x,y)` where ax is the instance created e.g. via `fig.add_subplot`.

An example for the wireframe plot can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_demo.html).

The following code (using the code from the question)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

width = 1
dx = 0.1
X = np.arange(-width, width, dx)
Y = np.arange(-width, width, dx)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    Z.append(np.zeros(len(X[i])))

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

produses the following plot

[image]

---

[*] To be precise here; you can call the class method `plot_wireframe`, but you would then need to supply it with the instance like

```
Axes3D.plot_wireframe(ax, X, Y, Z)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I was using Jupyter. So normally when I create plots I don't normally have to create figures or subplot or all the like. So I guess I assumed the line I had would create the 3D plot.

Comment: You always create figures and subplots, independent of where you type in your code.

Comment: why is that? jupyter allows you not to, no?

Comment: Jupyter is just a way to interprete python code. The result of the code may be presented in a different way, but the python code that produces the result is the same everywhere. Any matplotlib plot will consist of a figure and at least one axes object, and they need to be created somewhere.

Comment: So where are they created in jupyter if I don't explicitly have them?

Comment: I think you would need to provide an example, otherwise we will turn in circles here.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) example online. 
I've pasted it in your code example and I got the following code + plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

width = 1
dx = 0.1
X = np.arange(-width, width, dx)
Y = np.arange(-width, width, dx)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    Z.append(np.zeros(len(X[i])))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Hope this helps! I ran it with python 3.5, using the spyder IDE.

Cheers,
Dave